# Install a full eclipse from command line?

Tags: eclipse, installation

I want to provide developers a ready-to-use eclipse environment with all the needed plugins. I want to make the installation reproducible. How to do it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Dockerfile fragment installing a new eclipse to /opt/eclipse with GEF and PMD entirely from command line.

For the first run, you can browse the ftp site for the right version to download.

For the second run you can figure out plugin ids from "what is already installed", and repos from "Install New Software". I cannot tell a reliable way to figure out repos for marketplace plugins though, but so far I was lucky with google.

Here is a script to run after installing the needed package on top of a clean system-wide installation as user:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "RUN /opt/eclipse/eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director\\"
cat ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_*/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/epp.package.jee.profile/.data/.settings/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.prefs |
    awk -F/ '{print $2}'|
    grep '^http'|
    sort|
    uniq|
    sed 'sA_A/Ag;s/\\:/:/;s/^/\t-repository /;s/$/\\/'
ls ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_*/plugins/ |
    sed 's/_.*//;s/^/\t-installIUs /;s/$/\\/'
ls ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_*/features/|
    sed 's/_.*//;s/^/\t-installIUs /;s/$/.group\\/'
echo -e "\t-noSplash"
```

(you will need to hand-tweak it, but will contain everything installed)

Important additional information provided by @howlger (thanks!):

> See Eclipse help (e.g. -roaming if you want to create an Eclipse
>   package that can be moved/shipped to others). In an Eclipse
>   Marketplace item you can click on the download icon (below the Install
>   button) to get the repo URL.

```
RUN wget "http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/eclipse//technology/epp/downloads/release/2019-03/R/eclipse-jee-2019-03-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz" -O /tmp/eclipse.tar.gz;\
    cd /opt ; tar xzf /tmp/eclipse.tar.gz;\
    rm /tmp/eclipse.tar.gz
RUN /opt/eclipse/eclipse \
    -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director \
    -destination /opt/eclipse \
    -bundlepool /opt/eclipse \
    -profile SDKProfile \
    -repository https://dl.bintray.com/pmd/pmd-eclipse-plugin/releases/4.2.0.v20190331-1136 \
    -repository http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/5.0.0_gef-master_4403 \
    -repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-03 \
    -installIUs net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.feature.group \
    -installIUs org.apache.commons.io \
    -installIUs org.apache.commons.lang3 \
    -installIUs org.eclipse.xtext.sdk.feature.group \
    -installIUs org.eclipse.emf.sdk.feature.group \
    -installIUs org.eclipse.sdk.ide \
    -installIUs org.junit \
    -installIUs org.eclipse.fx.runtime.min.feature.feature.group \
    -installIUs org.eclipse.fx.runtime.min.feature.feature.group \
    -installIUs org.eclipse.gef.common.source.feature.group \
    -installIUs org.eclipse.gef.common.feature.group \
    -installIUs org.eclipse.gef.common.sdk.feature.group \
    -installIUs org.eclipse.gef.geometry.sdk.feature.group \
    -installIUs org.eclipse.gef.fx.sdk.feature.group \
    -installIUs org.eclipse.gef.mvc.sdk.feature.group \
    -installIUs org.eclipse.gef.mvc.examples.source.feature.group \
    -installIUs org.eclipse.gef.layout.sdk.feature.group \
    -installIUs org.eclipse.gef.graph.sdk.feature.group \
    -installIUs org.eclipse.gef.zest.sdk.feature.group \
    -installIUs org.eclipse.gef.zest.examples.source.feature.group \
    -installIUs org.eclipse.gef.dot.sdk.feature.group \
    -installIUs org.eclipse.gef.cloudio.sdk.feature.group \
    -noSplash
```

Comment: See [Eclipse help (e.g. `-roaming` if you want to create an Eclipse package that can be moved/shipped to others)](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html). In an [Eclipse Marketeplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/) item you can click on the download icon (below the _Install_ button) to get the repo URL.